# Wifi passwords Ubuntu after disk change

Tags: wireless-networking, ubuntu

I changed my ssd with Xubuntu 16.04 from one laptop (T420s) to another Thinkpad (also T420s). Everything worked fine. Just, Iam wondering why I have to add again al my wifi passwords. Are they in any way hardware connected? Shouldn't they just be saved on the disk and be still available on the new laptop?

Answer (score 2):

The connection links probably the SSID and your MAC address, so when you change your WLAN device, the parameters are probably unused.
Not sure about that, but it would make sense !

EDIT : it is that, for sure.

Check the file in "**/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*SSID***" and you'll see your own MAC address in the config file !

If you want to keep all the password, just do a **sed "s/OLD_MAC/NEW_MAC/" -i ./*** when into the system-connections folder, it should then work !

Answer (score 0):

This question could be directed to Stack Exchange ubuntu section. I am not an expert on the knowledge, but as far as I can tell, It is tied to your Mac address.

> Network or wifi passwords can be found in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections. There is a file for each connection with its configuration, also you need root privileges to read them but the password isn't encrypted.

Quoted from this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/139329/where-are-passwords-saved

You should see the information related to it.

Hopefully, this helps you.